# What kind of message should I display for processes that are queued because other users are currently running the process?

Tags: language, best-practice, workflow, instructions, messaging

Let's say user number 1 goes in and starts running a big process that can only have one instance running at a time. In the meantime 2 more users attempt to run the same process while it is still running.

Does the following messaging follow best practices for this scenario?

[image]

For example this is what the 3rd person would see:

[image]

Comment: When you say 'stay here and wait your turn', does this dialog stay open and give updates?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Is it possible you can prevent them from trying to initiate the process to start with, so they don't encounter a dialog?

Ideally, if the system can be aware of what jobs are running, you could have indicators, such as a disabled button in the main view, and explain *why the job can't be run by them at this time.* This way they see the system status and capabilities before any interaction.

You might be able to offer a notification when the queue clears, but I don't know enough about your application to understand if this is possible.

[image]

#### If you must use a dialog, and can't notify them

If your constraints do require some kind of dialog, make clear:

**What the status is:** In your title 'Processing request' makes it look like the action they initiated is happening: It's not, and they're now in a queue they didn't know of before.

[image]

If the queue clears, you can animate a transition, explain what changed, and surface the controls necessary to complete the task:

[image]